# How to create a world of stage?

Tags: slam, navigation, stage, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a world of stage with online slam.
I found that even in move_base_gmapping_5cm.launch it uses the static world which made before not dynamic during slam process.
How to create a world of my room during slam and used by rviz?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10636/how-to-create-a-world-of-stage?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_base_gmapping_5cm.launch does generate a map dynamically while being run. Only Stage (the simulator) has access to *a priori* map data.

There isn't a way to feed a dynamically generated map into Stage online.  If you think about it, this makes sense: the simulator needs to know what's in the world to simulate the robot's sensor data.

If you want to generate a SLAM map of your own environment, take a look at the [slam_gmapping tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials).  You could then use that map in a Stage `.world` file to simulate a robot in your environment.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-19**:
What I want is making a stage file *.world.How to make it?  Thank you~

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-05**:
@sam did you manage to create your .world file?